# send JSON object in POST request AFNetworking , iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using `AFNetworking` to post data into the web. The information I have is the `URI` which is `baseURL/post_user_info` and they want `input` as **A JSON object containing each of the name-value pairs.** In the code written below I've set the name-value pair in a dictionary. My question is how to make it's json and send it as input value?

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?post_user_info",BaseURLString];
NSString *escapedPath = [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"input_1": @"hello world",
                             @"input_2": @"my@you.com",
                             @"input_3": @"newworldorder"};
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:kNilOptions error:nil];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

[manager POST:escapedPath parameters:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
 }failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
 }];
```

I've updated the code because now I have generated the JSON but if I run the code now it give me Error: 400 which means If input_values is empty, a bad request error will be output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@interface AFJSONRequestSerializer : AFHTTPRequestSerializer**

> AFJSONRequestSerializer`is a subclass of`AFHTTPRequestSerializer`that encodes parameters as JSON` using `NSJSONSerialization`.

add this `AFJSONRequestSerializer`  is used for send JSON not a Raw Data  add this and try once

```
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
```

**e.g**

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?post_user_info",BaseURLString];
NSString *escapedPath = [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

 /**************  karthik Code added  ******************/
 AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
 manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
 manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
      /**************  karthik Code added  ******************/

    NSDictionary *params = @{@"1": @"hello world",
                             @"2": @"my@you.com",
                             @"3": @"newworldorder"};
[manager POST:escapedPath parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
          NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
           NSLog(@"json == %@", json);

     } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }];
```

**Update Params**

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"1": @"hello world",
                         @"2": @"my@you.com",
                         @"3": @"newworldorder"};
 NSMutableDictionary *modify = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[modify  setObject:params forKey:@"input_values"];
```

you get output of

[image]

Comment: hey! this works great... it's successful now... but the response object is `<7b227374 61747573 223a3430 302c2272 6573706f 6e736522 3a224261 64207265 71756573 74227d>` which is not a normal response. Is this because I'm passing wrong values in dictionary? or where else should I be looking for?

Comment: @TalhaCh - everything is correct, `responseObject` is the Data we need to serlize the data at now, So check the updated answer in **Success** block

Comment: are you trying  this {
    "input_values": {
        "input_1": "Hello",
        "input_2_3": "John",
        "input_2_6": "Smith",
        "input_4": "My paragraph"
    }
}

Comment: yes exactly this is what I'm trying to do. By the form on the web have only three fields.

Comment: @TalhaCh - check the Update Params answer

Comment: Well I saw your comments on this question but can you answer the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38896170/how-to-send-input-in-json-form-for-nested-values-in-nsdictionary/38897004 as you are already familiar with the issue.

Comment: getting 400 Bad Request as I want to send that nested data with my POST request as mentioned in the php code. I'm doing it from this https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/web-api/#post-forms

Comment: @TalhaCh - I will Update the answer in soon

Comment: Hey can you answer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114702/making-nested-json-in-nsdictionary-from-coredata