# How to send input in JSON form for nested values in NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

If the code for input a simple non-nested values is:

```
$values = array('input_values' => array('input_1'   => 'Testing',
                                        'input_2'   => 'Testing',
                                        'input_3'   => 'Testing',));
```

and in `Obj-C` it will go as:

```
 NSDictionary *params = @{@"input_1": @"Testing",
                             @"input_2": @"Testing",
                             @"input_3": @"Testing"};

    NSMutableDictionary *modify = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [modify  setObject:params forKey:@"input_values"];
```

**Then how do we convert and send this nested code in obj-C?**

```
$forms = array(
       array(
         'title'          => 'API Generated 10',
         'description'    => 'This is the description',
         'labelPlacement' => 'top_label',
         'button'         => array(
                   'type' => 'text'
         ),
        'confirmations'   => array(
                   array(
                    'id' => 0,
                    'name' => 'Default Confirmation',
                    'type' => 'message',
                    'message' => 'Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.',
                    'isDefault' => true,
                   ),
             ),
        'fields'          => array(
                   array(
                    'id' => '1',
                    'label' => 'My Text',
                    'type'  => 'text'
                   )
                   array(
                    'id' => '2',
                    'label' => 'My Text 2',
                    'type'  => 'text'
                   )
            ,
      ),
    );
```

UPDATE:
Based on the answers below if I implement this:

```
// Initially Crate one Main Dictionary for Save
    NSMutableDictionary *modify = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    NSMutableArray *ParamArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSDictionary *type = @{@"type": @"type" };

    NSDictionary *original = @{@"title": @"API Generated 10",
                               @"description": @"This is the description for the form generated by the API",
                               @"labelPlacement": @"top_label",
                               @"button":type
                               };

    // NSArray * svalues = original.mutableCopy;
    modify = original.mutableCopy;



    // store all Fields in one array
    NSDictionary *fieldsparams = @{@"id": @"1",
                                   @"label": @"My Text",
                                   @"type": @"text"};
    NSArray * fieldsvalues = fieldsparams.mutableCopy;
    [modify setObject:fieldsvalues forKey:@"fields"];

    NSDictionary *confirmationssparams = @{@"id": @"0",
                                           @"name": @"Default Confirmation",
                                           @"type": @"message",
                                           @"message":@"Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.",
                                           @"isDefault":@YES
                                           };
    NSArray * confirmationsvalues = confirmationssparams.mutableCopy;
    [modify setObject:confirmationsvalues forKey:@"confirmations"];


    [ParamArray addObject:modify];

    NSString *escapedPath = [string stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

    //1
    AFHTTPSessionManager* manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:escapedPath parameters:modify progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];
         NSLog(@"json == %@",json);

     }failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
     }];
```

It still gave me `400 Bad request`. As based on previous experience I need `NSMutableDictionary` of the above data in order to send it as JSON Object in `parameters` of `AFNetworking`. If I pass it `NSMutableArray` it doesn't work.

Comment: dictioanaries are represented by {} and arrays are by [] in obj-c.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri yes I know that. The code I wrote in Objective-c is working 100% fine for the php written above it. But I'm unable to convert the code below into obj-c and need help in that.

Comment: The code in obj-c is not a correct translation of code in php at the first line. In php you declared the dictionary in an array, whereas in obj-c you just declared a dictionary

Comment: What I'm saying is, wherever you see array(), replace it with @[] and , for the array contents, you already had the answer.

Comment: can you updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like

```
NSDictionary *fullData = @{
                                     @"title": @"API Generated",
                                     @"description": @"This is the description for the form generated by the API",
                                     @"labelPlacement": @"top_label",
                                     @"button":@{@"type": @"text"},
                                     @"confirmations": @{
                                                                      @"id": @0,
                                                                      @"name": @"Default Confirmation",
                                                                      @"type": @"message",
                                                                      @"message": @"Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.",
                                                                      @"isDefault": @true,
                                                            },
                                     @"fields": @[
                                                    @{
                                                      @"id":@1,
                                                      @"label":@"My Text",
                                                      @"type":@"text"},
                                                    @{
                                                      @"id":@2,
                                                      @"label":@"My Text 2",
                                                      @"type":@"text"}
                                                    ],
                                                    };
```

Otherwise it'll give you Bad request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code:

```
    NSArray *fieldsArr =  //your fieldsArr
    NSArray *confirmationsArr = //your confirmationsArr
    NSArray *buttonArr = //your buttonArr

    NSMutableDictionary *modify = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [modify  setValue:@"Titlr" forKey:@"title"];
    [modify  setValue:@"Disciption" forKey:@"description"];
    [modify  setValue:@"lablPlacement" forKey:@"labelPlacement"];
    [modify  setObject:buttonArr forKey:@"button"];
    [modify  setObject:fieldsArr forKey:@"fields"];
    [modify  setObject:confirmationsArr forKey:@"confirmations"];

    NSMutableArray *mainArr = [NSMutableArray new];

    [mainArr addObject:modify];

//Make request

NSError *error;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"[JSON SERVER"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                   cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                               timeoutInterval:60.0];

[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mainArr options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: I have to send this as JSON object so I just can't add `Data` as key all by myself.

Comment: @TalhaCh Then you need to convert "mainArr"  to JSON data.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I need to pass as an input with my POST request

Comment: Can you try to pass main array as parameter?

Comment: the answer below is doing the same. But by passing Array it's not working.

Comment: @TalhaCh I have updated my answer. Please try this. and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It will look like

```
NSArray * params = @[
                       @{
                           @"title" : @"API Generated 10",
                           @"description"    : @"This is the description",
                           @"labelPlacement" : @"top_label",
                           @"button"         : @{
                                                    @"type" : @"text"
                                                },
                           @"confirmations"  : @[
                                        @{
                                           @"id" : @0,
                                           @"name" : @"Default Confirmation",
                                           @"type" : @"message",
                                           @"message" : @"Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.",
                                           @"isDefault": @"true",
                                       }
                                   ],
                           @"fields" : @[
                                    @{
                                       @"id" : @1,
                                       @"label" : @"My Text",
                                       @"type"  : @"text"
                                       },
                                    @{
                                       @"id" : @2,
                                       @"label" : @"My Text 2",
                                       @"type"  : @"text"
                                       }
                                   ]
                           }
                       ]
```

Comment: @iSashok so if I wanted to give this whole as a JSON object to my post request I should just do this `[manager POST:escapedPath parameters:array progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)` right?

Comment: @ISashok, dictionary shud be in @{ .. }

Comment: @iSashok - in question everything is dictionary bro

Comment: @iSashok - PHP alternate of iOS [] ->Dictionary , {} - > array in PHP

Comment: @Talha Ch I updated answer with final variant, try it

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik not everything is a dictionary

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik in this `array(array( ` the first array() without key and it just array

Comment: @iSashok - Ok , then your wish

Comment: I'm getting '400 Bad request' here :/

Comment: @Talha Ch try to change this flag to `@"isDefault": @"true",`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem-

```
 NSMutableArray *MainArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //first dictionary
 NSDictionary *subDic1 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                  @"API Generated 10",
                                                                  @"This is the description",
                                                                  @"top_label",
                                                                  @{@"type":@"text"},
                                                                  nil]

forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"title",@"description1",@"labelPlacement",@"button", nil]];

    //second dictionary

    NSArray *arr1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  @{
    @"id":@0,
    @"name":@"Default Confirmation",
    @"type":@"message",
    @"message":@"Thanks for contacting us! We will get in touch with you shortly.",
    @"isDefault":@true
    },
                     nil] ;

 NSDictionary *subDic2 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:arr1, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"confirmations", nil]];

    //third dictionary

    NSArray *arr2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  @{@"id":@1,@"label":@"My Text",@"type":@"text"},
  @{@"id":@2,@"label":@"My Text2",@"type":@"text"},
                     nil] ;

NSDictionary *subDic3 = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:arr2, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fields", nil]];

    //now merge all dictionaries in one main array

    [MainArray addObject:subDic1];
    [MainArray addObject:subDic2];
    [MainArray addObject:subDic3];
```

Comment: if I use MainArray in `[manager POST:escapedPath parameters:MainArray progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)` it should work right?

Comment: Well it's not working. I'm getting `400 Bad request`