# Making Nested JSON in NSDictionary from CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data

I don't know if the title goes exactly with the question or not but if you feel it's missing something kindly edit the question.
I want to send parameter in specific format like `JSON` to `AFNeworking` in order to save the data on server.
I've an `NSArray` in which is named `fetchedDX` and I'm loading it with values from CoreData as `fetchedDX = [Diagnoses MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate];` which is getting the right values as I'm using it's count at one place and it is giving me the right count. This is the hardcode NSDictionary I'm preparing to send:

```
NSDictionary *superBillData = @{
      @"appointmentID": @"ABC",
      @"patientID": @"ABC",
      @"createdBy": @"ABC",
      @"lastChangedBy": @"ABC",
      @"Diagnoses":@[
            @{
                @"Code":@"hello world",
                @"shortDescription": @"my@you.com"
            },
            @{
                @"Code":@"hello 2",
                @"shortDescription": @"Lorem Ipsum"
                },
            ]};
```

Here the `Diagnoses` key is the one sending multiple objects. Now I've this data in `fetchedDX` array as core data gave me but I don't know how to make a dynamic `NSDictionary` because this array can have a count of one or more than one. So based on every value I've to create this:

```
@{
  @"Code":@"hello world",
  @"shortDescription": @"my@you.com"
 }
```

Here is the picture of my entity:
[image]

Any ideas how can this be achieved?

Comment: Is there any relationship involved?

Comment: How many attributes does this `Diagnoses` entity have? Can you share the `Diagnoses.h` file?

Comment: @Adeel yes there is an entity called `SuperBill` it's in one to many relationship with `Diagnoses`. Whereas superBill have the values above `Diagnoses` in `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I see and I assume that `Code` and `shortDescription` are the attributes of the `Diagnoses` entity, right? I need to confirm this because you'll use these attributes to get what you desire.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what it is. `Code` and `shortDescription` are the attributes of the `Diagnoses`.

Comment: Please try the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `Code` and `shortDescription` are the attributes of your `Diagnoses` entity. In the `Diagnoses.h` declare an instance method `- (NSDictionary *)dictionary;` and do this in your `Diagnoses.m` file.

```
- (NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    NSArray *keys = @[@"Code", @"codeDescription"];
    NSDictionary *dict = [self dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];

    return dict;
}
```

Then where you prepare the parameters dictionary change your code to this.

```
NSMutableArray *diagnosesArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (Diagnoses *obejct in fetchedDX) {
        [diagnosesArray addObject:[obejct dictionary]];
    }

    NSDictionary *superBillData = @{
                                    @"appointmentID": @"ABC",
                                    @"patientID": @"ABC",
                                    @"createdBy": @"ABC",
                                    @"lastChangedBy": @"ABC",
                                    @"Diagnoses":diagnosesArray};
```

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for but kindly just tell me one thing that which class is `Diagnoses.h`? `Diagnoses+CoreDataProperties.h` or `Diagnoses+CoreDataClass.h` because this is what xcode generated for when I created NSManagedObject Subclasses.

Comment: And also in `NSArray *keys = @[@"Code", @"shortDescription"];` there is a relationship field called `superBill`. I've updated my question.

Comment: Do it in `Diagnoses+CoreDataClass.h`.

Comment: If you need only `Code` and `shortDescription` then this would do. You don't need to worry about the relationship I guess.

Comment: Yes indeed you don't need to worry about the relationship with `superBill`. You need values of two attributes of your entity so that's all you need to do.

Comment: By following the answer I'm getting this `Diagnoses =     (
    );` but there are like 11 objects in this entity. Let me update my question based on that,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126097/discussion-between-adeel-and-talha-ch).